# Django - Retrieve or get data from selected foreign key field

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Relatively new to Django, I'm working on a Django project and attempting to retrieve particular foreign key object into variable when it's selected in Form.

`model.py`

```
class item_category(models.Model):
    idItemCat = models.CharField(primary_key=True max_length=5)
    nameCategory = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nameCategory

class item_code(models.Model):
    idItemCat = models.ForeignKey(item_category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    idItemCode = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.idItemCode
```

I know I could retrieve object with making QuerySet such as `.objects.last()` and `.objects.filter()` or else, but it's just retrieve objects from database or existing data. What I'm about to do is, when a user submit a new data it'll retrieve particular foreign key object based on what I'm selected in [this Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sBKD.png), so I could put into variable.

Any idea how should do it? it would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should look at the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) on forms.  They are excellent, and will teach you the right way to handle forms, a complicated topic.

To answer your question directly, it looks like you already have the html part, and as long as it has the form tag, like this:

```html
<form action='your_view' method='post'>
    ...
</form>
```

Then in your view you could do something like this:

```py
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = item_category.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('name_attribute_of_your_input'))
```

I'd need to see more specifics to give you a better answer, but there are several issues you should fix first.

First, your class names should be capitalized, field names lower case, and second,are you sure you want to make a CharField the primary key?  You can, but for most cases, the automatically generated integer pk that Django creates is best.

```py
class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    # Django will create an integer pk for you
    # idItemCat = models.CharField(primary_key=True max_length=5)
    nameCategory = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nameCategory

class ItemCode(models.Model):
    idItemCat = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    # Again, just let Django generate the primary key
    # idItemCode = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.idItemCode
```

Comment: First, okay got it all class names should be capitalized. Second, the reason I've decided to make a Charfield as Primary Key in ItemCategory Model is, at first I thought it was the easier way to retrieve particular foreign key objects. Because actually with this way, I want to make a custom Primary Key in ItemCode Model that contain particular Foreign Key object that I've asked earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but there is nothing *wrong* with using a custom primary key if you want it.   Django will, however, automatically add the pk of the foreign key into the model, you don't need to match them yourself.  check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) out.  Either way, did my answer not work?  It still should even with your custom pk.  Anyway, good luck @zaidan.